# Загрузка картинок на сервер и безопасность

Tags: php, безопасность

Здравсвтвуйте!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно обработать картинку на сервере? Чтобы пользователь не смог ложно подсунуть файл типа (picture.gif.php) и потом его выполнить. Либо есть случаи, когда хакер с помощью Perl скрипта формирует нужный ему заголовок и отправляет его на сервер и он понимает, что это картинка, а на самом деле исполняемый файл.

В общем, какой способ для загрузки картинок наиболее железобетонный? Может быть есть выдержки самого кода? Буду рад, если приведете пример!

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Не пытаться запустить на выполнение загруженные пользователем файлы - не вариант?

Comment: @Yaant, Пользователь может запустить свой файл.  При загрузке нужно проверить изображение это или нет.

Comment: @Yaant, загрузив файл, злоумышленник, зная путь до него, перейдёт к нему в браузере и сможет управлять сервером

Comment: Вот этот момент, поподробнее, пожалуйста: "зная путь до него, перейдёт к нему в браузере и сможет управлять сервером". Во-первых, откуда он узнает путь? Во-вторых, пусть даже знает. Ну, перейдет он к нему в браузере, сервер отдаст ему этот файл обратно, а дальше-то что? Как он, получив обратно свой файл, сможет управлять сервером?

Comment: @Yaant сервер не отдаёт файлы php, он интерпретирует. <?php
system($_GET['command']);
?>
 server/shell.php?command=any_Unix_shell_command

Comment: А зачем настраивать сервер так, чтобы он пытался интерпретировать загруженные пользователем изображения вместо того, чтобы просто отдать их пользователю?

Comment: @Yaant, А зачем вы пишите много лишних вопросов, вместо того, чтобы ответить на четко поставленную в теме задачу?